# Error when I return on TableViewController (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm a new Swift programmer. I'm building my first app with TableViewController + NavigationController.

In my app, I can see this:

[image]

If I click on Plus button I can see this View:

[image]

Then I compile all field and then I click on OK button. But I have this error:

```
2017-04-20 16:23:48.158 ArduinoHomeKit_bis[3238:795882] -[LuciKit id]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61000026a700
2017-04-20 16:23:48.162 ArduinoHomeKit_bis[3238:795882] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LuciKit id]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61000026a700'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107745b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001045c0141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001077b5134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001076cc840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001076cc3b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   ArduinoHomeKit_bis                  0x0000000103fc0603 _TFC18ArduinoHomeKit_bis28ListaLuciTableViewController14tornaAllaListafCSo17UIStoryboardSegueT_ + 435
    6   ArduinoHomeKit_bis                  0x0000000103fc098a _TToFC18ArduinoHomeKit_bis28ListaLuciTableViewController14tornaAllaListafCSo17UIStoryboardSegueT_ + 58
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000105903bbf -[UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 214
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000105903ab6 -[UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate _perform:] + 83
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010566ea1f -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 157
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000104ea8d22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001052e35c7 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 149
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000104ea8d22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010502d25c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010502d577 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010502d6eb -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 822
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010502c4b2 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000104f1649a -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2707
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000104f17bb0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4114
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000104ec47b0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001056a7adc __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2926
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010569fa3a __handleEventQueue + 1122
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001076ebc01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001076d10cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001076d05ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001076d0016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001096fca24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    27  UIKit                               0x0000000104ea70d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    28  ArduinoHomeKit_bis                  0x0000000103fc3ce7 main + 55
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001086e565d start + 1
    30  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

After click OK this is the code that I try to execute:

```
@IBAction func tornaAllaLista(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
        do {
            var vistaDettaglio: AggiungiLuceViewController = segue.source as! AggiungiLuceViewController
            if(vistaDettaglio.nuovaLuce != nil && vistaDettaglio.nuovaLuce?.id == 0){
                self.listaLuci.append(vistaDettaglio.nuovaLuce!)
                self.tabella.reloadData()
            }else{

            }
        } catch let errore {
            print("[CDC] problema tornaAllaLista")
            print("  Stampo l'errore: \n \(errore) \n")
        }
    }
```

> EDIT
>   This is the code that I execute when I click on OK button:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        //se il pulsante cliccato è diverso da OK torno indietro
        if sender as? NSObject != self.buttonOK{
            return
        }

        let nomeLuce = self.textNomeLuce.text!
        let pinArduino = Int16(self.textPinArduino.text!)
        let tipoLuce = self.textTipoLuce.text!

        if(nomeLuce.characters.count>0){
            //ho inserito almeno un carattere
            LuciKitCoreDataController.shared.addLuce(descrizione: nomeLuce, pin_arduino: Int(pinArduino!))
            self.nuovaLuce = LuciKit()
            self.nuovaLuce?.descrizione = nomeLuce
            self.nuovaLuce?.pin_arduino = pinArduino!
            self.nuovaLuce?.id = 3
        }else{
            let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Attenzione", message: "Inserire un nome per la Luce", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated:true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

If I try to execute this line code:

```
self.nuovaLuce?.descrizione = nomeLuce
```

I have an error

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance means, that your function you are try to call is not there or recognized. It could be, that you have not connected the @IBAction to your button in your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that this is the offending line:

```
vistaDettaglio.nuovaLuce?.id == 0
```

Object stored under `novaLuce` doesn't contain a `method` called `-id`, as it seems to be.

Comment: I have do a debug, and I can execute all tornaAllaLista method never error. The problem I think is on the after this method. 
Another items, if I try to comment this line code 
self.listaLuci.append(vistaDettaglio.nuovaLuce)

I don't have error